# Database schema design: more optimal schema

Tags: xml, database, database-design

I'm going to build a schema for the following XML file:

```
<Item ItemID="1045677572">
<Bids>
    <Bid>
        <Bidder Rating="1097" UserID="catann1">
            <Location>Longmont, Colorado</Location>
            <Country>USA</Country>
        </Bidder>
        <Time>Dec-10-01 06:43:24</Time><Amount>$0.99</Amount>
    </Bid>
...
</Bids>
<Seller Rating="87" UserID="efritz68"/>
</Item>
```

XML: Location and Country information is optional for Bidder. But, Seller don't need that information. A bidder can be a seller at the same time. A user may bid on multiple items. In that case, his Rating, Location, and Country information are the same across all bids. A user may have two separate ratings as a bidder and a seller, in case the seller is also bidding on other item(s)

I'm not sure which schema is more optimal to store Users.
Here's my schema:

## 1)

- User (UserID, Location, Country)
- Bidder (UserID, Rating)
- Seller (UserID, Rating)

## 2)

- Bidder (UserID, Rating, Location, Country)
- Seller (UserID, Rating)
- User (UserID)

Comment: Can a user really have a different rating for bidding and selling? That's not how the real world works, where users each have a rating, eg this site there isn't a question reputation and a separate answer reputation

Comment: Yes, rating is different. I forgot to add this info. Thanks

Comment: For a given user, is there a different "rating" on each bid he/she makes?

Comment: a user may bid on multiple items. In that case, his Rating, Location, and Country information are the same across all bids. A user may have
two separate ratings as a bidder and a seller, in case the seller is also bidding on other item(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema *is* (whether you like it or not):

```
Item (ItemID, SellerUserID, ...)
User (UserID, BidRating, SellRating, ...)
Bid (UserID, ItemID, Amount, Timestamp, ...)
```

Your XML is a denormalized version of this schema.

Comment: I think it's a nice way. Thanks!